# Windows 10 OpenSSH issues from new network

Tags: windows-10, ssh, firewall, openssh

I wanted to be able to SSH into my windows machine from my laptop while on a trip. I set up OpenSSH, configured firewall options and got everything running. While at home, I was able to run `ssh MACHINENAME@IP` from my laptop and connect fine. The command would prompt me to enter my password and I was able to connect.

Now that I'm away, my connections appear to be getting bounced. I get a number of different errors

`connect to host IP port 22: Host is down`

`connect to host IP port 22: Operation timed out`

`ssh: connect to host IP port 22: No route to host`

`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

I'm able to access my machine with an extremely laggy screen share and I'm trying to figure out how to get SSH working again.

Some basics:

OpenSSH is running

OpenSSH Firewall is unchanged (I've pasted the full thing below)

Running `ssh MACHINENAME@IP` on my windows machine works

I thought this was a firewall issue since it worked at home (even through my laptop was using a VPN?) but not away from home. I disabled windows firewall just to check but that didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone know how to address this issue?

Full firewall printout

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *ssh*

Name                  : OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP
DisplayName           : OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)
Description           : Inbound rule for OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)
DisplayGroup          : OpenSSH Server
Group                 : OpenSSH Server
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Any
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 :
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local
```

OpenSSh running:

```
Get-Service sshd

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  sshd               OpenSSH SSH Server
```

Comment: The IP you used was it an intranet or Internet IP address? What subnet was it in?

Comment: I'm a simple man. I used the IPv4 address that came up when I ran `ipconfig`. Subnet is `255.255.255.0`

Comment: 255.255.255.0 isn’t what I am asking for, I am asking if the IP address you attempted to use was a public or private IP address. Saying you connected to the address listed by *ipconfig* doesn’t tell us anything

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the issue was with port forwarding on the router

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail?